# How do I enable user interaction on child elements but ignore user interaction on the parent?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, event-handling

In the following diagram, S, P, C's are all subclasses of UIView. C's are children of P. P is a child of S. I want S and C's to respond to touches, but I want P to ignore all touches and propagate them to S.

```
 _____________________
| S                  |
|  ______________    |
| | P            |   |
| |              |   |
| |  ___         |   |
| | |   |        |   |
| | | C |        |   |
| | |___|   ___  |   |
| |        |   | |   |
| |        | C | |   |
| |        |___| |   |
| |______________|   |
|____________________|
```

I can't just do `p.userInteractionEnabled = NO` because that would disable C's as well.

If you are wondering why I need to do this, I want to have a structure similar to Facebook chat heads. The avatars, close button, and comment blurbs can be my C's. They can all be wrapped in a P, which has a transparent background and takes up the whole screen. P is the main view of a UIViewController that only handles chatting logic. Let's say the user tries to tap the Like button (owned by S). Then P should not block that tap - it should let S handle it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass a UIView and override - pointInside: withEvent: like below.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint localPoint = [self convertPoint:point fromView:self];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([subview pointInside:localPoint withEvent:event]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try cutting P out of the picture all together, I'm not sure what purpose it's serving beyond being a container. If you're looking to manage multiple Cs simultaneously, try putting them into an array, or an IBOutletCollection (if they're IBOutlets). You generally don't want two viewControllers on screen, with the same frame, both visible at the same time (pretty much exactly for this reason). You might consider having some object that's a chatModel, which can provide the needed info to S's viewController on demand, and have S directly present Cs.

Comment: I like to object orient my code using UIViewController composition (`addChildViewController:`). In beginner's iOS programming, you usually create one and only one UIViewController to present a page's worth of content. As the interface becomes more complex, the beginner would add more and more controller logic to that one and only view controller, making the code unruly. By composing many child UIViewControllers inside a main UIViewController, one may delegate responsibility into different classes.

Comment: You may not realize it, but UITabBarController and UINavigationController use child view controller composition to separate code. Those are wrapper controllers that show and hide many child controllers. Imagine if the tab bar and the navigation bar did not have this clean structure - then you'd be writing every one of your view controllers in one file!

Comment: To go round trip into what I'm doing: I'm creating a chat view controller that links chatting events with chatting views. The main view of this chatting controller is P. Anytime I feel like a page needs chatting capability, I just call `addChildViewController:chatViewController` and set the main view to overlay the entire page. Here is where the problem arises: even though the main chat view is transparent, it is still intercepting events.

Comment: Child view controllers are great, no question! However, you'll notice that in the examples you provided, the children of the container controllers aren't taking up the entire screen, and the parent/child views aren't "overlapping" (i.e. both presenting their own content in overlapping areas... You have a tab bar on the bottom of the screen, and then the child view controller's view above that, but no UI from the tab bar is visible/interactable "underneath" the child view controller)

Comment: So when you're using container controllers, you'll want the children to have their own space... i.e. nothing happens behind them in the view hierarchy that's interactable. So in your case, I think having a chat model object, perhaps one that can return chat views, and then a protocol that individual view controllers can implement for displaying chat bubbles, is probably the way to go.